# How to find files from current directory based on date?

Tags: bash, find

How can I find files from the current directory which have been created/modified e.g. yesterday? Or day before yesterday, or eg. 20131010?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

List files modified in the last 24 hours :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -mtime -1
```

List files modified on certain dates (oct 8-10 in this case) :

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -newermt 2013-10-08 ! -newermt 2013-10-11
```